# Help! Magento XMLHttpRequest cannot load after domain change

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, domain

I swapped domains in the same server
and I made the mistake that at first I put wrong base urls after moving `http://domain` not `http://domain/myfolder` and at first I did not clean cache and the var folder I added a bit later cause it was in .gitignore.
My credentials in the `local.xml` are correct I think and new database stuff.

All works in the page - alltough  -at first there was a redirect loop that I got rid of with changing `web/url/redirect_to_base`  to 0 in database. The file rights are OK I think, I was changing them all 777 and got no success

ALL that uses **XMLHttpRequest** is not working and it is panic since the page should be live for 1. december :(

This is what I get from console:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load** `http://domain/myfolder/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/615802c44a2f15b66a4322a1f91934e2/?SID=j2q3l1jvbjgoi2lu8a2embpsf6&isAjax=true`. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

and  then 
**XHR failed loading: POST** `"http://domain/myfolder//index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/615802c44a2f15b66a4322a1f91934e2/?SID=j2q3l1jvbjgoi2lu8a2embpsf6&isAjax=true".`

Answer (score 0):

So  - the answer

I was missing www in the front of base urls. Some linux issue I was told.
In the other domain it was working without somehow. 
So I am still WTF about it...